# How to replace repeated pattern of characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a string that has pairs of random characters repeating 3 times within it, for ex `"abababwhatevercdcdcd"` and i want to remove these pairs to get the rest of the string, like `"whatever"` in the former example, how do i do that?

I tried the following:

```
import re
re.sub(r'([a-z0-9]{2}){3}', r'', string)
```

but it does not work

Comment: How about `"wabababhatevercdcdcd"` -- should that be `"whatever"` as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need backreferences here in order to repeat the match that was actually made, as opposed to trying to make a new match with the same pattern:

```
([a-z0-9]{2})\1\1
```

---

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'([a-z0-9]{2})\1\1', r'', "abababwhatevercdcdcd")
'whatever'
>>> re.sub(r'([a-z0-9]{2})\1\1', r'', "wabababhatevercdcdcd")
'whatever'
```

Comment: btw `re.sub(r'([a-z0-9]{2}){3}', r'', "wabababhatevercdcdcd")` returns `cd` not `whatever`!!

Comment: np, just mentioned it so that others don't get confused ;)

Answer (score 1):

For more than one character, you can use :

```
(.{2,})\1+
```